# SAGA tools for scripts

Tags: python, saga

Is there any way to use SAGA tools to a standalone Python script outside of QGIS that can run with Windows compiler?

Comment: There's a python API if that helps: http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_api_python/index.html and they have extensive documentation on their tools: http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/index.html

Comment: this seems to need visual studio 2014 i want to use it if it's possible without any other program only from compiler